# User Entered Parameter in Crystal Reports with the Report Viewer in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to do a simple thing.  I want the user to enter the date on a form and for the report viewer to show a report reflecting the transactions of that date.  Using Crystal Reports, I have created a parameter of type date.  I put a selection formula referencing that date and ran it.  I get a flash of the report viewer followed by a screen that asks for the parameter.  I enter the parameter and the form closes.  So I tried dropping the record selection formula.  The same thing happens - the form opens, asks for the date then closes when I hit OK and closes the form.   I think the problem is the way I'm calling it.  Please take a look and kindly help if you can:

```
        reports.BalanceDetail report = new reports.BalanceDetail();
        crystalReportViewer1.ShowLogo = false;
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        report.SetDataSource(MSDataSet);
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        crystalReportViewer1.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter in the crystal report and generate a formula field based on this parameter.